# Starting JasperServer: This script requires root privileges

Tags: java-8, ubuntu-14.04, jasperserver

This is my second day with both tomcat and Jasperspft. so far I have installed and configured tomcat and it has started. But, i am unable to start JasperReports Server.

from this directory:

> /opt/tibco/jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0/scripts/linux

I run command

> sudo ./jasperserver start

Then I get the error:

> Starting JasperServer This script requires root privileges

And from:

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html

I get 3 applications:

> /
>
> host-manager
>
> manager

When I first installed everyting I used to get a forth application `JasperServer` but does not starte then I decided to undeploy it to deploy it again but unfortunately it desappeared.

then I downloaded `jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0-bin.zip` and extracted the WAR file from it called `jasperserver.war`. Then when I try to choose the file and deploy it from `http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html` then browser goes to empty page

> This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Then when I look to the file `manager.2015-12-06.log` it says the following:

> 06-Dec-2015 00:14:49.460 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: list:
>   Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost' 06-Dec-2015 00:18:14.292
>   SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: FAIL -
>   Deploy Upload Failed, Exception:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException:
>   the request was rejected because its size (156405033) exceeds the
>   configured maximum (52428800)  java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException:
>   the request was rejected because its size (156405033) exceeds the
>   configured maximum (52428800) at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2704) at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2950)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1077)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:185)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:618)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException:
>   the request was rejected because its size (156405033) exceeds the
>   configured maximum (52428800) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.(FileUploadBase.java:811)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2637)
>   ... 29 more

I noticed the file upload size limit but the xml file configurations I found are all set to -1, which is unlimited.
one more thing, I changed jasper configuration to chnage posgresql port number to the default 5432 as I alreadjy had it installed. I did not want to use the one that comes with tomcat.

Please help me start the JasperReports Server (jasperserver?)

jdk8
ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you tried copying the war file to the <tomcat-dir>/webapps directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't go into scripts/linux folder. Just go into your installation location. In your case /opt/tibco/jasperreports-server-cp-6.2.0.

Then run

sh ./ctlscript.sh start

on the terminal. You will need root privileges for this.